# How can i make contents in Iframe affect the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have html,javascript and jquery inside my webpage but when i put it in a iframe it doesnt affect the page with the iframe tag.Is there any html code which can allow the contents in the iframe affect the page with the iframe?

Comment: Whilst both Answers so far rely on `window.parent` - which is correct, I'd be curious to know the application; ie. Why do you need your iframe to change your parent? (there's probably a better way to get the same result)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.parent` to get the id of the parent window, then use that to make changes with Javascript:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("someElement").innerHTML = "Some new content";
```

if you're using jQuery you can do this:

```
window.parent.$("#someSelector").someFunction();
```

...but you must have jQuery loaded in the **parent** window for this to work.

Comment: can i use that in a html tag?

Comment: No. HTML tags will only affect the presentation of the current document. You need Javascript to affect other documents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in JavaScript.

through the `window.parent.SomeJsMethodDefinedInTheParent()` you can call arbitrary JS in the parent.

Just define a method in the parent page and call it